# Is there any impact whatsoever of enabling FILESTREAM on active SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, filestream

I may have to enable Filestream on a live SQL Server at work, but first need to know about the possible impact/implications of doing so on the performance/operation of the databases held therein.

I have done some reading and have not found anything daunting, but since it's fairly important, thought I had better check on here.

Comment: Make sure you actually 'need' Filestream - http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/high-performance-filestream-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 1):

Enabling filestream by it self will not have any impact on the databases not using filestream. Queries on filestream data will be done using system cache not buffer cache so you might need to make sure that the SQL server service is not using all availible resources, see http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/filestream-and-filetable-in-sql-server-2012.html

Answer (score 1):

you can enable using
In the SQL Server Properties dialog box, click the FILESTREAM tab. Select the Enable FILESTREAM for Transact-SQL access check box. If you want to read and write FILESTREAM data from Windows, click Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access. Enter the name of the Windows share in the Windows Share Name box.

[image]

There's a really good blog post by [Paul Randal on SQL Server 2008: FILESTREAM Performance](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-FILESTREAM-performance.aspx) - check it out. There's also a 25-page [whitepaper on FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh461480) available - also covering some performance tuning tips.